# how to deal with com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException

Tags: java, mysql

I am writing an application to display elements from the database. I have 2 packages Application and database. 
Application has 3 classes namely `DB`, `ResultSetTableModel`, `Parameters.` 
database has 5 classes we consider only User(my focus for the question).

I got this:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')     
VALUES('5','via','v','Director')' at line 1
```

when i run my class User.

i think on my opinion my main problem comes from here, this code:

```
public String insertQuery(String tableName, String[] tableContent)
{
    openDBCon();
    int i;
    SQL = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " VALUES(";

    for(i = 0; i <= tableContent.length - 1; i++)
    {
        SQL += "'" + tableContent[i] + "'";

        if(i < tableContent.length - 1)
        {
            SQL += ",";
        }
    }

    SQL += ")";
    return this.executUpdate(SQL);
}
```

from the DB class

this are the details of my system environement

```
Data base server version:

Server: 127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP
Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.6.16 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Protocol version: 10
User: root@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

web server:

Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.5.9
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: bf9ad53b11c9a57efdb1057292d73b928b8c5c77 $
PHP extension: mysqli 

phpMyAdmin:

Version information: 4.1.6, latest stable version: 4.6.3
```

this is the code for DB:

```
package Application;

import java.net.Socket;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class DB {
//declarations
Connection myConnection;
Statement myStatement;
String SQL;
String url;
String username;
String password;
Socket client;
int Port;
String Host;

//Constructor
public DB(String url, String username, String password, String Host, int Port)
{
    this.url = url;
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.Host = Host;
    this.Port = Port;
}

public Connection openDBCon ()
{
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        myConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());//to display the exact location of where the problem is the message
    }
    return myConnection;
}

//closes DB connection
public Connection closeDBCon()
{
    try
    {
        myConnection.close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
         System.err.println(ex);
    }
    return myConnection;
}

//Request execution
public ResultSet executeQuery(String sql)
{
    openDBCon();
    ResultSet myResultSet = null;
    try
    {
        myStatement = myConnection.createStatement();
        myResultSet = myStatement.executeQuery(sql);
        System.out.println(sql);
    }
    catch(SQLException ep)
    {
         System.err.println(ep);
    }
    return myResultSet;
}

//Update request execution
public String executUpdate(String sql)
{
    openDBCon();
    String myResult = "";
    try
    {
        myStatement = myConnection.createStatement();
        myStatement.executeUpdate(sql);
        myResult = sql;
    }
    catch(SQLException es)
    {
         myResult = es.toString();
    }
    return myResult;
}

//Display all
public ResultSet querySelectAll(String tableName)
{
    openDBCon();
    SQL = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName;
    System.out.println(SQL);
    return this.executeQuery(SQL);
}

//Display all with parameters
public ResultSet querySelectAll(String tableName, String state)
{
    openDBCon();
    SQL = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " WHERE " + state;
    System.out.println(SQL);
    return this.executeQuery(SQL);
}

//
public ResultSet querySelect(String[] columnName, String tableName)
{
    openDBCon();
    int i;
    SQL = "SELECT ";

    for(i = 0; i <= columnName.length - 1; i++)
    {
        SQL += columnName[i];

        if(i < columnName.length - 1)
        {
            SQL += ",";
        }
    }

    SQL += " FROM " + tableName;
    return this.executeQuery(SQL);
}

//
public ResultSet fcSelectCommand(String[] columnName, String tableName, String state)
{
    openDBCon();
    int i;
    SQL = "SELECT ";

    for(i = 0; i <= columnName.length - 1; i++)
    {
        SQL += columnName[i];

        if(i < columnName.length - 1)
        {
            SQL += ",";
        }
    }

    SQL += " FROM " + tableName + " WHERE " + state;
    return this.executeQuery(SQL);
}

//Insert data
public String insertQuery(String tableName, String[] tableContent)
{
    openDBCon();
    int i;
    SQL = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " VALUES(";

    for(i = 0; i <= tableContent.length - 1; i++)
    {
        SQL += "'" + tableContent[i] + "'";

        if(i < tableContent.length - 1)
        {
            SQL += ",";
        }
    }

    SQL += ")";
    return this.executUpdate(SQL);
}

//
public String insertQuery(String tableName, String[] columnName, String[] tableContent)
{
    openDBCon();
    int i;

    SQL = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " (";
    for(i = 0; i <= columnName.length - 1; i++)
    {
        SQL += "'" + columnName[i] + "'";

        if(i < columnName.length - 1)
        {
            SQL += ",";
        }
    }

    SQL = ") VALUES(";
    for(i = 0; i <= tableContent.length - 1; i++)
    {
        SQL += "'" + tableContent[i] + "'";

        if(i < tableContent.length - 1)
        {
            SQL += ",";
        }
    }

    SQL += ")";
    return this.executUpdate(SQL);
}

public String updateQuery(String tableName, String[] columnName, String[] tableContent, String state)
{
    openDBCon();
    int i;

    SQL = "UPDATE " + tableName + " SET";
    for(i = 0; i <= columnName.length - 1; i++)
    {
        SQL += columnName[i] + "= '" + tableContent[i] + "'";

        if(i < columnName.length - 1)
        {
            SQL += ",";
        }
    }

    SQL = " WHERE " + state;
    return this.executUpdate(SQL);
}

//Delete
public String queryDelete(String tableName) 
{
    openDBCon();
    SQL = "DELETE FROM " + tableName;
    return this.executUpdate(SQL);
}

//Delete parameters
public String queryDelete(String tableName, String state) 
{
    openDBCon();
    SQL = "DELETE FROM " + tableName + " WHERE " + state;
    return this.executUpdate(SQL);
}
```

}

This the Parameterss class

```
package Application;


public class Parameterss 
{
    public static String IPHOST = "127.0.0.1"; //address
    public static String HOST_DB = "jdbc:mysql://" + IPHOST + ":3306/stock_management";
    public static String USERNAME_DB = "root";
    public static String PASSWORD_DB = "";//

    public static int PORT = 11111;
    public static String USER;
}
```

i want to pull attention on the function insertQuery and executUpdate of the DB.

And finally the code for User

```
package database;

import Application.DB;
import Application.Parameterss;
import Application.ResultSetTableModel;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class User extends javax.swing.JFrame 
{
    ResultSet myResultSet;
    DB myDB;

public User() 
{
    myDB = new DB(new Parameterss().HOST_DB, 
                new Parameterss().USERNAME_DB, 
                new Parameterss().PASSWORD_DB, 
                new Parameterss().IPHOST, 
                new Parameterss().PORT);
    initComponents();
    table();
}

public void table()
{
    String a[] = {"id", 
                "id_user", 
                "username", 
                "password", 
                "type"};
    myResultSet = myDB.querySelect(a, "users");
    table_user.setModel(new ResultSetTableModel(myResultSet));
}

void refresh()
{
    txtid.setText("");
    txtus.setText("");
    txtpa.setText("");
    comty.setSelectedItem("Typeeee");        
}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    table_user = new javax.swing.JTable();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    txtus = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    txtpa = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    txtsearch = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    txtid = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    comty = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
    jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    search_cat = new javax.swing.JComboBox();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tekton Pro Ext", 1, 24)); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setText("Users");
    jLabel1.setAlignmentX(0.5F);
    jLabel1.setAutoscrolls(true);
    getContentPane().add(jLabel1);
    jLabel1.setBounds(201, 6, 85, 37);

    table_user.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {
            {null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null, null}
        },
        new String [] {
            "id", "id_user", "username", "password", "type"
        }
    ) {
        Class[] types = new Class [] {
            java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class
        };
        boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
            false, false, false, false, false
        };

        public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return types [columnIndex];
        }

        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return canEdit [columnIndex];
        }
    });
    table_user.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            table_userMouseClicked(evt);
        }
    });
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(table_user);

    getContentPane().add(jScrollPane1);
    jScrollPane1.setBounds(10, 54, 488, 100);

    jButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
    jButton1.setText("Edit");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(jButton1);
    jButton1.setBounds(160, 180, 80, 23);

    jButton2.setText("Search");
    jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(jButton2);
    jButton2.setBounds(290, 300, 80, 30);

    jButton3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
    jButton3.setText("Delete");
    jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(jButton3);
    jButton3.setBounds(260, 180, 80, 23);

    jButton4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
    jButton4.setText("Refresh");
    jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(jButton4);
    jButton4.setBounds(360, 180, 80, 23);

    jButton5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
    jButton5.setText("Add");
    jButton5.setName("Add"); // NOI18N
    jButton5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton5ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(jButton5);
    jButton5.setBounds(60, 180, 80, 23);

    jLabel2.setText("type");
    getContentPane().add(jLabel2);
    jLabel2.setBounds(30, 410, 50, 30);

    jLabel3.setText("password");
    getContentPane().add(jLabel3);
    jLabel3.setBounds(30, 360, 46, 14);

    jLabel4.setText("username");
    getContentPane().add(jLabel4);
    jLabel4.setBounds(30, 310, 40, 14);

    jLabel5.setText("id_user");
    getContentPane().add(jLabel5);
    jLabel5.setBounds(30, 260, 50, 20);
    getContentPane().add(txtus);
    txtus.setBounds(110, 310, 140, 30);
    getContentPane().add(txtpa);
    txtpa.setBounds(110, 360, 140, 30);

    txtsearch.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            txtsearchActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(txtsearch);
    txtsearch.setBounds(390, 300, 110, 30);
    getContentPane().add(txtid);
    txtid.setBounds(110, 260, 140, 30);

    comty.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Cashier", "Director" }));
    getContentPane().add(comty);
    comty.setBounds(110, 410, 140, 30);

    jLabel6.setText("Search By Category");
    getContentPane().add(jLabel6);
    jLabel6.setBounds(280, 260, 105, 30);

    search_cat.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "id_user", "username", "password", "type" }));
    getContentPane().add(search_cat);
    search_cat.setBounds(390, 260, 110, 30);

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        


//Update button
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    if(txtid.getText().equals("") || 
            txtus.getText().equals("") || 
            txtpa.getText().equals("") || 
            comty.getSelectedItem().equals("Typeeee"))
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please fill in the information");
    }
    else
    {
        String[] colon = {"id_user", 
                        "username", 
                        "password", 
                        "type"};
        String[] information = {txtid.getText(), 
                                txtus.getText(), 
                                txtpa.getText(), 
                                comty.getSelectedItem().toString()};
        String id = String.valueOf(table_user.getValueAt(table_user.getSelectedRow(), 0));
        System.out.println(myDB.updateQuery("users", 
                                            colon, 
                                            information, 
                                            "id ='" + 
                                            id + 
                                            "'"));
        table();
        refresh();
    }
}                                        

//Search button
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    if(txtsearch.getText().equals(""))
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please enter keyword(s)");
    }
    else
    {
        if(search_cat.getSelectedItem().equals("id_user"))
        {
            myResultSet = myDB.querySelectAll("users", "id_user LIKE '%" + txtsearch.getText() + "%' ");
            table_user.setModel(new ResultSetTableModel(myResultSet));
        }
        else if(search_cat.getSelectedItem().equals("username"))
        {
            myResultSet = myDB.querySelectAll("users", "username LIKE '%" + txtsearch.getText() + "%' ");
            table_user.setModel(new ResultSetTableModel(myResultSet));
        }
        else if(search_cat.getSelectedItem().equals("password"))
        {
            myResultSet = myDB.querySelectAll("users", "password LIKE '%" + txtsearch.getText() + "%' ");
            table_user.setModel(new ResultSetTableModel(myResultSet));
        }
        else if(search_cat.getSelectedItem().equals("type"))
        {
            myResultSet = myDB.querySelectAll("users", "type LIKE '%" + txtsearch.getText() + "%' ");
            table_user.setModel(new ResultSetTableModel(myResultSet));
        }
    }
}                                        


//Refresh button
private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    refresh();
    table();
}                                        


//Add button
private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    if(txtid.getText().equals("") || 
       txtus.getText().equals("") || 
       txtpa.getText().equals("") || 
       comty.getSelectedItem().equals("Typeeee"))
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please fill in the information");
    }
    else
    {
        String[] colon = {"id_user", 
                        "username", 
                        "password", 
                        "type"};
        String[] information = {txtid.getText(), 
                                txtus.getText(), 
                                txtpa.getText(), 
                                comty.getSelectedItem().toString()};
        System.out.println(myDB.insertQuery("users", 
                                        colon, 
                                        information));
        table();
        refresh();
    }
}                                        

private void txtsearchActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                         

//Fills table values in the text fields when clicking on the value in the table
private void table_userMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
    txtid.setText(String.valueOf(table_user.getValueAt(table_user.getSelectedRow(), 1)));
    txtus.setText(String.valueOf(table_user.getValueAt(table_user.getSelectedRow(), 2)));
    txtpa.setText(String.valueOf(table_user.getValueAt(table_user.getSelectedRow(), 3)));
    comty.setSelectedItem(String.valueOf(table_user.getValueAt(table_user.getSelectedRow(), 4)));
}                                       


//Delete button
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    String id = String.valueOf(table_user.getValueAt(table_user.getSelectedRow(), 0));
    if(JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this,
        "Delete??",
        "Sure?",
        JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION) == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)
{
    myDB.queryDelete("users", "id" + id);
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
    table();
}                                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(User.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(User.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(User.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(User.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new User().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JComboBox comty;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JComboBox search_cat;
private javax.swing.JTable table_user;
private javax.swing.JTextField txtid;
private javax.swing.JTextField txtpa;
private javax.swing.JTextField txtsearch;
private javax.swing.JTextField txtus;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

i have a table called users with columns:

```
id
id_user
username
password
type
```

and i made id primary key and auto-increment.

It is not giving me this type of error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Field 'id' does not have a default value
```

When i run it i get the:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')     VALUES('5','via','v','Director')' at line 1
```

my primary key is already auto-incremented so did not add it in the insertQuery function of DB class and i considered that fact in the rest of the functions in DB class

i have tried for many days now but i still cannot insert, delete, update. but i can search and refresh

i even compared with a project of the same nature but with a different approach i made prior this one that on works but this one does not.

Comment: This error means you have a syntax error in your SQL query. output the full query to the console so it will be easier for you to see where the error is.

Comment: Thanks man. when i try this on the sql console it works:             INSERT INTO users (`id_user`, `username`, `password`, `type`)
VALUES ('11', 'samy', 's', 'Cashier').           But when when implement it in the code it screws up. please help me find that stubborn problem. please.

Comment: is this the exact query you got by doing `system.out()` or is it what you think that you run?

Comment: Hey fatman thanks for you intervention. i finally saw where the problem is. it is definitely not at the sql syntax on itself but in the code of the insertQuery method of my DB class that you can see in the previews post up.

Comment: i forgot a + in the SQL variable that is supposed to gather up the query. consequently the value of the previous SQL variable was not added to the new value so my insert syntax was thus not complete:

Comment: instead of writing this: SQL += ") VALUES("

Comment: i wrote this rather: SQL = ") VALUES("  without the plus sign. that is why the INSERT INTO tablename(...)...could not be added to the ) VALUES(

Comment: that is why the query itself was working when tried on the console but was not working when implemented in the code. just because of a plus.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your Help man.